# How to call Custom Module in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I am new to Drupal, I have made a custom module using PHP, which shows List of Student's with Information, and want to call it, on click of Submenu item, named, student Info. Please guide me by step wise step procedure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack, Neetu! Please give us some code and examples so we can help you with your question.

Comment: please read documentation before asking on stackoverflow https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules

Answer (score 1):

The starting place to look for generating a "page callback" (essentially making a url active in drupal) would be hook_menu. As suggested take a look at the documentation but a starting point to actually make your callback work would be this in a my_module.module file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function my_module__menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['student-info'] = array(
        'title' => 'Student Info', // This becomes the page title
        'description' => 'Information about students.', // this is the link description
        'page callback' => 'function_name_that_outputs_content', // this is the page callback function that will fire
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, // this is the type of menu callback, there are several that you can use depending on what your needs are.
    );

    return $items; // make sure you actually return the items.
}

/**
 * Output the page contents when someone visits http://example.com/student-info.
 */
function function_name_that_outputs_content() {
    $output = 'My page content'

    return $output;
}
```